# Subqueries return more than one row?

Tags: mysql, subquery

This is my Code but I need the group by option because I need to group the subqueries by Derparti, for example I need to find how many doctors work in each department, so I need my subqueries to return more than one row.

```
SELECT d.Dreparti,
  (SELECT avg(Paga)
   FROM dpaga dp
   WHERE d.titulli=dp.titulli
   GROUP BY Dreparti),
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Doktori
   GROUP BY Dreparti),
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM doktori d,
        Hospitalizimidata hd
   WHERE d.did=hd.did
   GROUP BY Dreparti),
  (SELECT sum(CmimipaTVSH)
   FROM faturat f,
        hospitalizimidata h,
        doktori d
   WHERE f.hid=h.hid
     AND h.did=d.did
     AND DataFatures BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY AS DATE) AND CAST(curdate() AS DATE)
   GROUP BY Dreparti) ,
  (SELECT sum(Cmimi)
   FROM faturat f,
        hospitalizimidata h,
        doktori d
   WHERE f.hid=h.hid
     AND h.did=d.did
     AND DataFatures BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY AS DATE) AND CAST(curdate() AS DATE)
   GROUP BY Dreparti) ,
  (SELECT sum(Cmimi)
   FROM pagesat p,
        faturat f,
        hospitalizimidata h,
        doktori d
   WHERE f.hid=h.hid
     AND h.did=d.did
     AND p.fid=f.fid
     AND DataFatures BETWEEN CAST(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 365 DAY AS DATE) AND CAST(curdate() AS DATE)
   GROUP BY Dreparti)
FROM doktori d
GROUP BY Dreparti;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Try to simplify your case, it is quite long for your question.

Comment: Pls provide expected output! I'm not sure that you can include all these queries in a single query.

Comment: Which table(s) contain this Dreparti field? Which table has all Dreparti values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have tagged your question with both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]. Please edit your question and delete one of those tags--they are for different dialects of SQL. Also, please try to cut down your code example, and specify an example of the result set you hope to get.

Comment: @Shadow Table doktori contains Dreparti

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your subqueries from the select list to from list as derived tables. Use the table / query as the first one that returns all (or at least the most) departments and left join the other derived tables on tge 1st one using the departments field. I'll give you a sample code for 3 subqueries, assuming that the doctors table has all departments:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Dreparti, COUNT(*) AS NoOfDoctors
   FROM Doktori
   GROUP BY Dreparti) t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Dreparti, avg(Paga) AS AvgPaga
   FROM dpaga dp inner join Doktori d
   ON d.titulli=dp.titulli
   GROUP BY Dreparti) t2 ON t1.Dreparti=d2.Dreparti
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Dreparti, COUNT(*) AS NoOfSomething
   FROM doktori d INNER JOIN
        Hospitalizimidata hd
   ON d.did=hd.did
   GROUP BY Dreparti) t3 ON t1.Dreparti=t3.Dreparti
```

However, I would use the master data table of departments as the leftmost table. Since you did not mention anything about it, I did not include it.